# Android enabled accessibility list

Tags: android, accessibility

I wanna do some research, do our users use the accessibility features or not? If they are using accessibility, what exactly do they use?

Easy to know if is accessibility enabled in common.
Just call

```
 val am = context.getSystemService(ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE) as AccessibilityManager
 am.isEnabled
```

However, I need a list of enabled/disabled features for creating an analytics map.
Ideally like:

```kotlin
val analyticsData = am
        .getAllAccessibilityFeatures()
        .map { it.name to it.isEnabled }

sendAnalytics(analyticsData)
```

But the code above is a pseudocode, how can I reach this goal?

Comment: This could violate their rights, just be careful about regulations such as GDPR. Also, you can't detect if users are actively using magnification on your app, for example. So while some things like screen readers and other settings can be listened to, others cannot. Also, if you want to measure how many disabled users use your app in order to decide whether you're going to make your app accessible, that's putting the cart before the horse. If they can't use it they won't. You need to make it accessible first.